# elementary OS - Viewing the full Ubuntu based version

Tags: pantheon-terminal, ubuntu

I would like to know how to get the long Ubuntu based version in Elementary OS

Output of `lsb_release -a -u`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And `lsb_release -a` :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description:    elementary OS Freya
Release:    0.3.2
Codename:   freya
```

As you can see none of the commands have the long Ubuntu version (like 14.04.3)

Comment: sorry, what do you mean " long Ubuntu version " ? apart from 14.04

Comment: @Ravan I mean like 14.04.3

Comment: what is `-u` option? I haven't know that. can you please let me know where can I find its description.

Comment: ```-u``` = Upstream

Comment: I can think of a way for you to see the "long" version, but it helps if you tell where are you going to use this info. Just curiosity or are you creating some kind of script that needs to know the version?

Comment: When installing drivers / xorg and those kinds of things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that running `uname -v` outputs the long Ubuntu based version. Here's the output of it : `49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015`

Comment: This is not the case anymore (at least in Loki). `uname -v` prints `#57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016`.

Comment: @DanielLe Yes , it seems not work work on my laptop running Loki (it did in Freya)